# Absorption Spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, visible-light, absorption

I just learnt what absorption and emission spectrum are. And our teacher introduced us to what [Quantum Dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dot) are. And showed us their absorption and emission spectra. 
And they look something like this 
                   [image]

I understand that the peaks of the spectra is supposed to match the transition energy in the QD. But why does the absorbance increase as the wavelength decreases? I am not aware of any QD transition energy at that wavelength. And this seems to be true for all the QD spectra I googled. Is it dependent on other substances in the solution or the film?

Please correct if I am mistaken.