# High resolution atmospheric absorption spectrum?

Tags: atmospheric-science

I am looking for a high resolution (at least 0.5 nm) spectrum showing atmospheric absorption (particularly for oxygen and water) in the wavelength region of 600-800 nm. I want to find windows of very low absorption in Earth's atmosphere. I've looked at several related stack exchange questions, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123299/absorption-cross-section-and-absorption-coefficient/123306#123306), and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123154/absorption-spectrum), but I have not yet find a good resource for this.

I found the [HITRAN database](http://hitran.org/) and some models that use the line intensities and other parameters from HITRAN.  The problem is that I haven’t found one that simulates bottom of atmosphere absorption.

This [SPECTRA](http://spectra.tsu.ru/home) model is almost what I want, but one of the inputs to the simulation is optical path length, and what I want is the absorption from a path through the whole atmosphere (and since temperature, pressure, etc varies across the atmosphere, I want a model simulation that accounts for this).